# PostgreSQL date in array format type

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have a column in PostgresSQL table that is defined as (_date). I am using DBeaver application. When I looked up the data type it says date[] which I think it’s an array. I am trying to create a similar table but unsure how to define that field column. Any suggestions please. Below the code I am using to get the data type of this field -

Select pg_typeof(“column_name”) from table_name limit 1

The above query returns date[]

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the same datatype, i am not not clear what you are asking what new table an where?

Comment: You mean define the data type as _date. I believe I can do that but is that an ideal way to define an array date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_date is only a synonym for date[]

with both you can insert dates like

```
CREATE tABLE test(dte_n _date)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE tABLE test1(dte_n date[])
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{2023_01_01}')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('{2023_01_01}')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('{2023_01_01,2023-02-02}')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
Select pg_typeof(dte_n) from test limit 1
```

| pg_typeof |
| --- |
| date[] |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
Select pg_typeof(dte_n) from test1 limit 1
```

| pg_typeof |
| --- |
| date[] |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UKz0z6dZ)

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback